# segmentation fault during realloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

First allow me to apologize for the formatting and the difficult code. I am new to C and Stack. Most of the messy code here are probably irrelevant to the problem but necessary to include for the context.

The code below runs into segmentation fault after the first call to realloc (noted in the comments). `return_file->target_line` is simply a 3D array, `i` is an element count of the first dimension of the 3D array. So I'm calling realloc on it to store additional 2D arrays (of type `char **`).

`NULL` returns of memory allocations were purposely omitted b/c the developement protocol specifically stated all memory allocations will be successful (which I have a doubt of).

I'm using my own memory check program. The error code I get is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ac63fb in reallochook () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I have looked at it for a very long time but can't seem to find what the problem is.

```
Mockfile *read_mockfile(const char filename[]) {
  Mockfile *return_file = NULL;
  FILE *input;

  if(filename != NULL && (input = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) {
    char **split_tmp, line[MAX] = {0};

    return_file = malloc(sizeof(Mockfile));
    return_file->rule_count = 0;

    /*read lines*/
    while(fgets(line, MAX, input) != NULL){
      if(line[0] != '#' && line[0] != '\n'){
        int j, i = return_file->rule_count;
        split_tmp = split(line);

        if(line[0] != '\t'){
          j = 0;


          /*target line. Realloc every string in three steps. Segementation fault occurs after this line below.*/
          return_file->target_line = realloc(return_file->target_line, (i + 1) * sizeof(char **));

          while(split_tmp[j] != NULL){
            return_file->target_line[i] = realloc(return_file->target_line[i], (j + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            return_file->target_line[i][j] = malloc(strlen(split_tmp[j]) + 1);
            strcpy(return_file->target_line[i][j], split_tmp[j]);
            j++;
          }
          return_file->target_line[i] = realloc(return_file->target_line[i], (j + 1) * sizeof(char *));
          return_file->target_line[i][j] = NULL;
        } else {
          j = 0;

          /*action line. Allocate every string in three steps*/
          return_file->action_line = realloc(return_file->action_line, (i + 1) * sizeof(char **));

          while(split_tmp[j] != NULL){
            return_file->action_line[i] = realloc(return_file->action_line[i], (j + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            return_file->action_line[i][j] = malloc(strlen(split_tmp[j]) + 1);
            strcpy(return_file->action_line[i][j], split_tmp[j]);
            j++;
          }
          return_file->action_line[i] = realloc(return_file->action_line[i], (j + 1) * sizeof(char *));
          return_file->action_line[i][j] = NULL;

          return_file->rule_count++;
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(input);
  }
  return return_file;
}
```

Comment: @MD XF, are you just talking about the curly braces not being on a new line? b/c that's a personal preference I'm purposely keeping.

Comment: Whatever works for you... works for you. But there are a few key improvements to be made, some small details that make big differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) expects its first argument to point to a valid block of memory or `NULL`, so after `malloc()` you should initialise:

```
return_file = malloc(sizeof(Mockfile));
return_file->rule_count = 0;
return_file->target_line = NULL; /* Add this */
```

This should resolve that crash.

Note also that `foo = realloc(foo, N);` is a bug, as `realloc()` can return `NULL`, so you need to handle that for completeness.

Comment: What is the reason behind this? Is it necessary for other allocation functions? i.e. `malloc()` and `calloc()`?

Comment: Which "this" are you referring to? The C standard defines the behaviour [as noted on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc); `NULL` return value checking is of course necessary for `malloc()` too, but for different reasons.